# Activity variable passing not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a variable "name" which is a string from one activity to another but for some reason when I get it from the intent it is null the code for the intent parts is below, Passing from List_Activity to OpenList activity

List_Activity.class

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenList.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", ListNames[pos]);
    System.out.println("Passing " + ListNames[pos] + " as listname");
    startActivity(new Intent(this, OpenList.class));
}
```

OpenList.class

```
//gets list name
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        name = extras.getString("name");
        System.out.println(name+ " has been passed as the name");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Return is null");
    }
```

It always returns "return is null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Change this

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenList.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", ListNames[pos]);
    System.out.println("Passing " + ListNames[pos] + " as listname");
    startActivity(new Intent(this, OpenList.class));                // correction here
}
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenList.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", ListNames[pos]);
    System.out.println("Passing " + ListNames[pos] + " as listname");
    startActivity(intent);                          // correction here
}
```

that means this `startActivity(new Intent(this, OpenList.class));` to `startActivity(intent);`

then you are not sending `Bundle` so get like below

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    System.out.println(name+ " has been passed as the name");
}else{
    System.out.println("Return is null");
}
```